# Tic Tac Toe Google App Engine tutorial confusion?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, google-cloud-endpoints

Operating System: Mavericks

I'm running through an Google Appengine Endpoints [example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/endpoints_tool#generating_a_discovery_doc) and from the command prompt I'm running:

> ./endpoints.sh get-discovery-doc packagename.YourApiClass

and getting an error:

> SEVERE: Received exception processing ./war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Could not locate /Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/bin/./war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
>       at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:140)
>       at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:75)
>       at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AppEngineUtil.getAppProperty(AppEngineUtil.java:82)
>       at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AppEngineUtil.getApplicationId(AppEngineUtil.java:41)
>       at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GenApiConfigAction.genApiConfig(GenApiConfigAction.java:86)
>       at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GetDiscoveryDocAction.getDiscoveryDoc(GetDiscoveryDocAction.java:85)
>       at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GetDiscoveryDocAction.execute(GetDiscoveryDocAction.java:66)
>       at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool.execute(EndpointsTool.java:68)
>       at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool.main(EndpointsTool.java:97)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml (No such file or directory)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:101)
>       at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:137)
>       ... 8 more
>
> Error: Could not locate /Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/bin/./war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml

how do I point the google app engine endpoints command line tool to the correct directory? Right now it seems that somewhere this directory ./war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml is set as the location of whatever file (appengine-web.xml maybe?) its looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to what I wrote below, according to Google "[Some features of the App Engine Java SDK tools are only available by running the tools directly from the command line](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse#Running_the_Command_Line_Tools)," so not using the the command line tool may come back and bite me in the future, but for now the Eclipse plugin will suffice. If anyone can provide insight on my question above, please share.

Here's a [Google page on the various command line functions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp).

I ended up using Eclipse with the [Google App Engine plug-in](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse) and that was so much easier and faster than using the command line tool to execute Google App Engine functions.
The Eclipse Google App Engine plugin also has Endpoints, which  generates APIs and client libraries for web, Android, and iOS clients from an App Engine application.

Here's the link for the [Google documentation on the Eclipse Google App Engine plug-in](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/).

Here's the link on [Using the Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse)

Here's the link for the page that has the [download instuctions for the Eclipse Google App Engine plugin](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started#installing).